# Understanding poorly written code, 2nd year CS past paper

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, coding-style

The question is to describe what the code does, what the function does.

The following code is part of the past exam papers for a 2nd year C and C++ module. The task is to describe what the following piece of code does. I've written the code exactly as presented, with some comments added by myself.

```
int g(int * y, unsigned size, int z) {
    int tmp = y[0];
    // what type is unsigned size? Int I presume. Why would you add an int to an array of ints?
    int * b = y + size; 
    y[0] = z;
    // I have the most difficulty understanding the following.
    while (1) if (*(--b)==z){y[0] = tmp; return b - y;};
    // are the following 3 lines ever even reached?
    y[0] = tmp;
    if (tmp == z) return 0;
    else return -1;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: "what type is unsigned size?" Why, `unsigned`, or, with family name, `unsigned int`.

Comment: Have to completely disagree with closing this question. It's marked `homework`, it's clear, and the OP has specific questions about the code which are clearly laid out and entirely answerable.

Comment: The question is to describe what the code does, what the function does.

Comment: +1 to what @T.J.Crowder said. Looks like a perfectly fine question to me.

Comment: Hint 1: adding a pointer and an int is of course standard pointer arithmetic. Assuming `size` is the length of the array `y`, `b` will point at the first memory location after the end of array `y`.

Comment: Ya, he doesn't know what the code does.  That's the question.  And btw, it is trying to find where z was in the int array y, swaps the locations of the first element and where z was in the array, and returns the index of where it was originally.  If not found, the array doesn't change and it returns 0.

Comment: Hint 2: The loop you don't understand decreases the memory location `b` until it finds an instance of `z`. Ask yourself: What does it return if it finds `z`? What happens if the array `y` passed to the function does not contain the value `z`?

Comment: Oh, and I think you're right about the last 3 lines. Don't see how they could be reached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// what type is unsigned size?
```

It's an `unsigned int` called `size`. You add it to a pointer as in normal pointer arithmetic - advance this pointer to the very end of the array.

```
while (1) if (*(--b)==z){y[0] = tmp; return b - y;};
```

OK, we've got

- `while(1)` = while(true), or 'loop forever'
- `*(--b)` pre-decrement b and read the value from that index of the array
- if we've found z, replace the first element with the value we read from it and return `b-y` - pointer arithmetic for the array index we're at

i.e. we're scanning backwards through the array to find the last instance of `z` and returning the index at which we found it. We will always find `z` in the array because we put it there as the first element, i.e. if `z` isn't in the array then we return 0.

```
// are the following 3 lines ever even reached?
```

No, I don't think so.

Comment: There's a problem with the code, though: if `size == 0`, the loop will start scanning backwards from the memory location _before_ the first element of `y`. This can't be good. In particular, there's no guarantee in this case that the loop will terminate normally. The loop will terminate either when it finds some random memory location that happens to have the value of `z` stored in it or it will crash when trying to dereference an illegal memory address.

Comment: @Ted yep, true - there's no range validation for `size` either way. Good spot!

Answer (score 7):

> what type is unsigned size

`unsigned` is short for `unsigned int`.

> Why would you add an int to an array of ints?

Pointers and arrays are not the same thing. The code you've shown is using pointers, not arrays. After the `int * b = y + size;` line, `b` is a pointer that points to the entry `size` entries from where `y` is pointing. For example, if `size` were `2`, `b` would be pointing to the third entry. ASCII-art:

```
+---------+
| entry 0 |<--- `y` points here
| entry 1 |
| entry 2 |<--- `b` points here if `size` is `2`
| entry 3 |
| entry 4 |
+---------+
```

> I have the most difficulty understanding the following.
>
> `while (1) if (*(--b)==z){y[0] = tmp; return b - y;};`

The loop looks at the entries in the memory pointed to by `y` starting with the entry *before* the one identified by `size`. If the entry is `==` to `z`, it sets `y[0]` to `tmp` and returns the index at which the entry was found (by using pointer arithmetic, `b - y` returns the number of entries between where `b` is pointing and the beginning of `y`. Since `--b` decrements the pointer, the loop works backward through the memory.

> are the following 3 lines ever even reached?

No. The `return` will exit the function when the first matching entry is found, which may be at the beginning (as `y[0]` is set to `z` early on). As Ted Hoff points out in the comments, though, the loop will start and continue past the beginning (where `y` is pointing) if `size` is `0` on entry, which would probably eventually cause the program to fail with a memory access violation.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Also Rup pointed out that y[0] is set to z at the start, so z will always be found.

Comment: @MikeGallagher: Doh, missed that bit. Fixed.

Comment: @MikeGallagher - `z` will not be found if `size == 0`.

Comment: @TedHopp: Oooooh. Yeah, well, it's not the only quality issue with the code. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing this code does is prove that the author is incompetent.
But I gather that's part of the assignment: understanding code written
by incompetent people.

For starters:

- `unsigned` is a valid C++ type, a contraction for `unsigned int`.  It's
  generally best avoided, unless your doing bit manipulations.
- There are no arrays in your code; you're adding an integer to a
  pointer.  And curiously enough, `[]` is not array indexation, but
  defined so that `a[b]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a+b)`.  (At least for
  the build in types.)  You might want to find a book about C, to explain
  this; in C++, we generally use `std::vector`, precisely to avoid all of
  this confusion about pointer arithmetic.

As for the part you have difficulty understanding: for starters, let's
write it in a sane manner:

```
while ( true ) {
    -- b;
    if ( *b == z ) {
        y[0] = tmp;
        return b - y;
    }
}
```

About the only thing which should cause an issue there is the return
statement: this is pointer subtraction; in this case, since `y` is the
first element of an array (judging from the rest of the code), `b - y`
calculates the index of the element pointed to by `b`.

The use of pointers here would be pure obfuscation, except that the
idiom is ubiquitous in C, and is carried on with iterators in C++.

And you're right that the code after the loop can never be executed; the
only way of leaving the loop is through the `return`.

A much cleaner way of writing the loop would be:

```
int i = size;
while ( i != 0 && y[i - 1] != z ) {
    -- i;
}
y[0] = tmp;
return i;
```

Comment: Your last piece of code doesn't seem quite right. For one, the braces are not balanced. Assuming that the indenting reflects the intended bracing, it's also not equivalent to OP's code (specifically when `size == 0`).

Comment: +1 just for the "...let's write it in a sane manner..." ;-)

Comment: @TedHopp I forgot the closing brace; I'll fix that.  As for the case when `size == 0`, the original code had undefined behavior in that case, so I don't think I'm required to be identical:-).

Comment: @JamesKanze this is not necessarily undefined behavior. The precondition could be that y-1 always contains z.

Comment: @maniek And that you pass the address of the second character in your array as argument:-).  That would work, but it doesn't really seem very likely (and I wouldn't like to maintain code written by someone who designs their interfaces like that).